# Layout gets shifted on different devices although im using constraint Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

so I'm building my first app, it's a remote control for an arduino device. Now I want it to look the same or at least similar on all android devices. I thought this would be achieved by using constraint layout. So I tried it out on two different devices:

1. xiaomi 9T Pro
2. Samsung Galaxy A5

Now the problem is:
It looks good on the xiaomi phone, but it looks horrible and shifted on the Samsung Galaxy A5. So only using constraint layout doesn't seem to be the solution. Now how can I achieve it, that this app looks the same on every phone?

Here is my code for the xml file of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChooseActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/possibleDevices"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Possible Devices to connect to: "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lvNewDevices"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remoteButton"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="104dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:onClick="openRemoteControl"
        android:text="Remote Control"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/temperatureButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.509"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/temperatureButton"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"


        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="104dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Temperature Monitor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/historyButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.524"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/historyButton"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"


        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="104dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:onClick="openHistory"
        android:text="Events"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"


        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="104dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
        android:onClick="openTerminal"
        android:text="Terminal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/possibleDevices"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFindUnpairedDevices"
        android:layout_width="207dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"


        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="104dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="104dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        android:onClick="btnDiscover"
        android:text="Discover"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/remoteButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvNewDevices"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="169dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="104dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="104dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="107dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="107dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is how it should look (xiaomi 9T Pro):
[image]

Here is how it looks on the samsung phone:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*So only using constraint layout doesnt seem to be the solution*

You were using a lot of **hardcoded sizes** on your views and because different phones have a different size your layout will not be responsive.

**With percentage you can make you layout responsive:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/possibleDevices"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Possible Devices to connect to: "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lvNewDevices"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/remoteButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:onClick="openRemoteControl"
    android:text="Remote Control"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/temperatureButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnFindUnpairedDevices"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/temperatureButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Temperature Monitor"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/historyButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/remoteButton"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/historyButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:onClick="openHistory"
    android:text="Events"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temperatureButton"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:onClick="openTerminal"
    android:text="Terminal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/possibleDevices"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/historyButton"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFindUnpairedDevices"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:onClick="btnDiscover"
    android:text="Discover"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/remoteButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvNewDevices"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

---

### How It works:

Now for every view, its size is measured up according to screen size, those are the important attributes:

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"
 app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
```

For more info check [this](https://wajahatkarim.com/2018/04/percentage-width/height-using-constraint-layout/)

Comment: thank you very much, man! I tried it out and it works so far. only problem is that on the samsung it kind of shrinks the buttons to much. is there a way to have something like minimum height/weight so that this doesnt happen?
Here is a picture of it: 
https://ibb.co/D4ZLWtR

Comment: Maybe something like this  `app:layout_constraintHeight_min="150dp"`

Comment: You can also change `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.05"`  to something bigger `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"`

Comment: @tamit abutbul ok thank you very much ill try it out. I added a picture of it here: https://ibb.co/D4ZLWtR

Comment: Ok, I see the problem, you just have text size that is too large' try to use some library to make your text responsive. [Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview), [ssp library](https://github.com/intuit/ssp)